# Looking for an horizontally asymptotic function with a very gentle slope

Tags: functions

Ok, so basically I am looking for a function which approaches 0... but very gently and ideally I would like to avoid the vertical hockey stick at the start of the asymptote.

I am creating a scoring system where the rank of a user translates into a specific score. I want the score to decrease as the rank decreases. However I want it to happen gently.

I looked at 1/x and some other polynomial functions. The problem is that all of them have a very steep vertical hockey stick when x is small. I want to be able to avoid that situation cause the decline is too sharp in the beginning.

The function doesn't have to be asymptotic. But those are the first that come to my mind when I think of the plot.

Have pasted an image of the ideal function graph.

Thanks!

[Ideal function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvyUz.jpg)

Comment: Why not using $1/(x+1)$?

Comment: @Crostul The problem with 1/(x+1) is that the initial slope is too sleep. I want it to be gentle right from around x=1,2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like $$f(x)=\frac1{x^\alpha+1}$$ for any $\alpha>0$ and $x\geq0$. Then the maximum will be $f(0)=1$, and you can make it decrease to $0$ as slowly (or quickly) as you like.

An alternative to a power of $x$ is to use logarithms, but then you are limited to a smaller domain (which may or may not be an issue for you).

Comment: This works great (for me) when α is between 0 and 1. Its not that bad even when α is between 1 and 2. After that the initial slope becomes to steep for my need. This is awesome. Thanks a lot!!